# Add message to an image java

Tags: java, message

My code keeps generating a blank image instead of a picture selected using pickAfile and the message. What am I doing wrong?

When after saving and compiling the image I select the image the text should appear on using pickAFile but only a blank window is generated. I think I'm having issues with my height parameter but I'm not sure how to fix it. the addMessage method is already part of the picture method so I don't think I need to include that

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Begin Java Exection"); System.out.println("");

    // created the variable 
    Picture p; 

    p = new Picture ();
    String filename; filename = FileChooser.pickAFile ();
    Picture pict;
    pict = new Picture (filename);

    int height = p.getHeight(); 
    p.addMessage("Love Life",640,480);

    p.show ();

    filename = FileChooser.pickAFile ();
    p.write (filename);

    System.out.println(""); System.out.println("End Java Exection");
}
```

Followed below commenters answer and now image is showing but the message is not:

here's the new code:

```
{
 public static void main (String[] args)

{ 
    System.out.println("Begin Java Exection"); System.out.println("");

    // created the variable 
    Picture pict; 

    pict = new Picture ();
    String filename; filename = FileChooser.pickAFile ();
    pict = new Picture (filename);

    int height = pict.getHeight(); 
    pict.addMessage ("Love Life", 1200, height - 20 );

    pict.show ();

        filename = FileChooser.pickAFile ();
        pict.write (filename);

    System.out.println(""); System.out.println("End Java Exection");
}


{
}}
```

Comment: Can add a little more description to your question. It is unclear the problem you're facing.

Comment: When after saving and compiling the image I select the image the text should appear on using pickAFile but only a blank window is generated.   I think I'm having issues with my height parameter but I'm not sure how to fix it. the addMessage method is already part of the picture method so I don't think I need to include that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is API we don't know but I see a simple mistake here:

```
Picture p;
p = new Picture ();

Picture pict;
pict = new Picture (filename);

p.addMessage("Hell is just a sauna.",640,480);
p.show ();
p.write (filename);
```

Do you see it now? You have two instances of `Picture`. `pict` is created with `filename`, but `p` is the one you show.

Comment: If your Picture is [this one](http://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/doc/Picture.html) it's possible your coordinates for addMessage should be `20,height-20` if you want to draw it in the bottom left. According to that doc the x is the leftmost position of the String (same for other AWT/Swing coordinates). IE you might be drawing it off the righthand side of the image.

Comment: NVM thank you that worked! I resized the image and the text showed up! thanks again!

Comment: With AWT/Swing coordinates the leftmost and topmost edges are 0. So higher numbers increase towards the right and bottom. Usually the Graphics draw a String so the coordinates given are the bottom left of the first character. For example, `[0,height]` draws anchored to the bottom left corner and visible but `[width,0]` draws anchored invisible off the top right corner. If it doesn't work to give a coord farther to the left maybe ask the professor if this is for a class since the doc doesn't say much.

Comment: And I see your edited comment now: no problem, good luck. : )